# Mudança de estrutura de tabela, perante colunas no banco de dados

Tags: html, python, django

Boa noite, tudo bem ?
Estou com um problema envolvendo o DJango e gostaria de saber se alguém pode ajudar.
Tenho uma tabela de carregamento de impostos, e funciona perfeitamente, porem existem clientes meus que não vão utilizar certas colunas desta mesma tabela.
Ex: tenho 3 clientes que só precisam pagar o impostos x, m,  d
E tenho outros que pagam os anteriores mais o y, z, w
Preciso que o DJango carregue as configurações da tabela  e retire os impostos que não serão utilizados da mesma quando for carregar o html

meu views.py :

```
from ctypes.wintypes import BOOL

from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Transparencia, Config
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.views import generic








class home(ListView):
    template_name = 'website/index.html'
    model = Transparencia
    context_object_name = "Transparencias"
```

meu urls.py :

```
from django.urls import path,\

    include

from .views import  home

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home.as_view()),

]
```

Parte do meu HTML que esta funcional, porem ainda nao funciona de fato do jeito que gostaria :

```
      <h1>Transparencia</h1>
     <div class="borderTop"></div>
       <div id="Transparencia-area">
         <div class="container">
           <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="tabela-Transparencia">
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                   <th scope="col">ID</th>
                   <th scope="col">Mes</th>
                   <th scope="col">Ano</th>
                   <th scope="col">Valor Receitas do Sitio </th>
                   <th scope="col">Receitas </th>
                   <th scope="col">Receitas Estado </th>
                   <th scope="col">Receitas Sefaz </th>
                   <th scope="col">Receitas Registro Civil </th>
                   <th scope="col">Receitas ISS  </th>
                   <th scope="col">Receitas Justica </th>
                   <th scope="col">Receitas MP </th>
                   <th scope="col">Receitas Diversas </th>
                   <th scope="col">Receitas FICSREI </th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                 {% for Transparencia in  Transparencias %}
                   {% if Transparencia.exibir_Transparencia %}
                     <tr>
                         
                         <td>{{ Transparencia.id }}</td>
                         <td>{{ Transparencia.mes }}</td>
                         <td>{{ Transparencia.ano }}</td>

                         {% if Transparencia.exibir_Receita_Sitio %}<td>{{ Transparencia.valorReceitaSitio  }}</td> {% else %}  <td>{{ '-----' }}</td>  {% endif %}
                         {% if Transparencia.exibir_Receita_Receita %}<td>{{ Transparencia.Receita  }}</td> {% else %}  <td>{{ '-----' }}</td>  {% endif %}
                         {% if Transparencia.exibir_Receita_estado %}<td>{{ Transparencia.estado  }}</td> {% else %}  <td>{{ '-----' }}</td>  {% endif %}
                         {% if Transparencia.exibir_Receita_sefaz %}<td>{{ Transparencia.sefaz }}</td> {% else %}  <td>{{ '-----' }}</td>  {% endif %}
                         {% if Transparencia.exibir_Receita_registro_Civil %}<td>{{ Transparencia.registro_Civil }}</td> {% else %}  <td>{{ '-----' }}</td>  {% endif %}
                         {% if Transparencia.exibir_Receita_iss %}<td>{{ Transparencia.iss }}</td> {% else %}  <td>{{ '-----' }}</td>  {% endif %}
                         {% if Transparencia.exibir_Receita_justica %}<td>{{ Transparencia.justica }}</td> {% else %}  <td>{{ '-----' }}</td>  {% endif %}
                         {% if Transparencia.exibir_Receita_mp %}<td>{{ Transparencia.mp }}</td> {% else %}  <td>{{ '-----' }}</td>  {% endif %}
                         {% if Transparencia.exibir_Despesa_Diversa %}<td>{{ Transparencia.diversas }}</td> {% else %}  <td>{{ '-----' }}</td>  {% endif %}
                         {% if Transparencia.exibir_Despesa_fIC_SREI %}<td>{{ Transparencia.fIC_SREI }}</td> {% else %}  <td>{{ '-----' }}</td>  {% endif %} 
                     </tr>
                   {% else %}

                   {% endif %}  
                 {% endfor %}
                 
             </tbody>
           </table>
         </div>
       </div>
```

Neste código, sempre que um imposto não for utilizado os caracteres:  '-----' , ocupam o espaço, porem eu gostaria de retirar de fato a coluna, pois NAO A POSSIBILIDADE DO cleinte mostrar um imposto em uma tupla e na outra não.

Desde já agradeço a todos

Comment: seu código já está pronto... só colocar o mesmo if na tag `<th>` e no else deixar vazio, remover essa tag com o -----  ...

Comment: Boa tarde @RovannLinhalis e muito obrigado, mas infelizmente quando realizei a altercarão, os cabeçalhos das tabelas '<th>' continuam sendo exibidos enquanto os  conteúdos '<td>' de fato somem, acredito que seja por conta da tag '{% for %}' que tenho logo depois do '<tbody>', que o código esteja funcionando para as tuplas.
Porem para o cabeçalho preciso que seja feita apenas uma iteração, se uso o for ele replica os '<th> varias vezes, precisava de uma função ou uma espécie de arquivo de configurações que seja lido e retorne as colunas a serem exibidas.
Continuarei pesquisando uma solução.